# Global variable is not being edited by function

Tags: python, loops, variables, syntax, global

I've done my fair share of toying around with the placement of `global user` within the code to see if it was missing somewhere but it does not appear to be. Basically when I call for `userInstance.getName()` after assigning the global `user` variable in this chunk of code seen here:

```
if(userName in nameList):
    for userdata in pklList:
        if userdata.getName() == userName:
            global user
            user = userdata
            print("user data found for user: " + user.getName())
```

it doesn't appear to actually make it to the global variable. here is the full version of the code at the moment:

```
import praw
import time
import re
import pickle
from classes import User



USERAGENT = 'web:CredibilityBot:v0.1 (by /u/ThePeskyWabbit)'
FOOTER = "^^I ^^am ^^a ^^bot! ^^I ^^am ^^currently ^^in ^^test ^^phase. ^^Read ^^about ^^me ^^[here](https://pastebin.com/jb4kBTcS)."
PATH = "C:\\Users\\JoshLaptop\\PycharmProjects\\practice\\commented.txt"
user = User.User("ERROR")

commentFile = open(PATH, 'rb')
commentList = commentFile.read().splitlines()
commentFile.close()

pkl = open("userpkl.pkl", 'rb')
pklList = []
print(pklList)

try:
    pickle.load(pkl)
    while(True):
        pklList.append(pickle.load(pkl))
except EOFError:
    pass
pkl.close()

nameList = []
try:
    for data in pklList:
        nameList.append(str(data.getName()))
except:
    pass

print(pklList)
print(nameList)


def addPoint(comment):
    message = "current name for user: " + user.getName()
    #userInstance.addScore()
    #userInstance.addComment(comment)
    #message = "Bullshit noted! " + userInstance.getName() + " now has a Bullshit rating of " + userInstance.getScore() + "\n\n" + FOOTER
    return message

def getRating():
    message = user.getName() + " has a Bullshit rating of: " + user.getScore()
    return message

def getCommentList():
    bullshitComments = user.getComments()
    return bullshitComments



auth = True
def authenticate():
    print("Authenticating...")
    reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1', user_agent=USERAGENT)
    print("Authenticated as {}\n" .format(reddit.user.me()))
    return reddit

commentLink = None

actions = {"!bullshit": addPoint(commentLink), "!bullshitrating": getRating(user), "!bullshitdetail":getCommentList(user)}
stringList = ["!bullshit", "!bullshitrating", "!bullshitdetail"]

while(auth):
    try:
        reddit = authenticate()
        auth = False
    except:
        print("Authentication Failed, retying in 30 seconds.")
        time.sleep(30)


def runBot():
    SUBREDDITS = 'test'
    global user

    while(True):
        print("Scraping 1000 comments...")
        for comment in reddit.subreddit(SUBREDDITS).comments(limit=1000):

            for word in stringList:
                match = re.findall(word, comment.body.lower())

                if match:
                    id = comment.id
                    commentFile = open(PATH, 'r')
                    commentList = commentFile.read().splitlines()
                    commentFile.close()

                    if(id not in commentList):

                        print(match[0] + " found in comment: " + "www.reddit.com"  + str(comment.permalink()))
                        commentLink = "www.reddt.com" + str(comment.parent().permalink())
                        print("Bullshit comment is: " + commentLink)

                        print("searching for user data")
                        userName = str(comment.parent().author)
                        flag = True

                        if(userName in nameList):
                            for userdata in pklList:
                                if userdata.getName() == userName:
                                    user = userdata
                                    print("user data found for user: " + user.getName())


                        elif comment.parent().author is not None:
                            print("no user found, creating user " + userName)
                            user = User.User(userName)
                            f = open("userpkl.pkl", 'ab')
                            pickle.dump(user, f)
                            f.close()
                            nameList.append(userName)
                            print("added to user to pkl file")

                        else:
                            print("username could not be retrieved.")
                            print("adding ID to log\n")
                            commentFile = open(PATH, 'a')
                            commentFile.write(id + "\n")
                            commentFile.close()
                            flag = False

                        if(flag):
                            try:
                                print(actions[match[0]])
                                #print("sending reply...")
                                #comment.reply(actions[match[0]])
                                #print("Reply successful. Adding comment ID to log\n")
                                #commentFile = open(PATH, 'a')
                                #commentFile.write(id + "\n")
                                #commentFile.close()

                            except:
                                print("Comment reply failed!\n")




runBot()
```

and whats weird is when I call `user.getName()` within the afformentioned snippit of code, it outputs the correct name and not "error" as it does when I call it in my `addPoint()` function.

print statements output as follows:

```
C:\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/JoshLaptop/PycharmProjects/practice/TestBot.py
[]
[<classes.User.User object at 0x03B59830>, <classes.User.User object at 0x03816430>]
['PyschoWolf', 'ThePeskyWabbit']
Authenticating...
Authenticated as CredibilityBot

Scraping 1000 comments...
!bullshit found in comment: link deleted for privacy
Bullshit comment is: link deleted for privacy
searching for user data
user data found for user: PyschoWolf
current name for user: ERROR
!bullshit found in comment: link deleted for privacy
Bullshit comment is: link deleted for privacy
searching for user data
user data found for user: ThePeskyWabbit
current name for user: ERROR
```

Comment: Where is "error" coming from?  I can't see anywhere in the code where you output "error".  If you are getting an error message, then please show it.  Are you sure you are initialising `user` before trying to use it?  Try initialising it in the outer code, near the top of your program.

Comment: from `user.getName()`

the default name as assigned in the top lines of the code is "ERROR"

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: well that's kind of tricky as I am loading in objects from a pickle file as well as authenticating an account with the reddit servers, reading in data from an .ini file to do so. I will try to write some code that will create this issue without needing the files I am using.

Comment: I was searching for "error" (as you wrote) not "ERROR".

Comment: my mistake. understandable

Answer (score 0):

In python if your code make an assignment to a variable then, unless explicitly stated, the variable is assumed to be a local. If you declare them explicitly they are instead global.

Globals are however "per module".

Something that often is not clear is that when you import a name what happens is that a copy of the imported **value** is made in the current module as a module global with the same name (or a different name if using also `as`. For example:

```
from xxx import user
# xxx.user has been copied to a globl named user

user = "baz"  # <--- this DOES NOT change xxx.user

xxx.user = "ohyeah"  # Now it changes xxx.user
```

Note that there is something "magic" in Python about this and it's that functions remembers in which module they were defined. Suppose I have:

```
# module.py

user = "No user yet"

def setUser(newUser):
    global user
    user = newUser

def getUser():
    return user

# program.py
from module import user, setUser, getUser

print(user)      # --> "No user yet"
print(getUser()) # --> "No user yet"

setUser("Hey")

print(user)      # --> "No user yet" (1)
print(getUser()) # --> "Hey"

user = "Foo"
print(user)      # --> "Foo"
print(getUser()) # --> "Hey" (2)
```

(1) happens because `user` is just a global of the program, not the global of the module. The value was copied from the module to the program at import time and that's all

(2) happens for the same reason. the code that was compiled in the module will see as globals that module, not the program. This happens despite the call is made in the program and the `getUser` variable (containing the function) is here. It's the function that "remembers" which are the globals it should access.

The code

```
from xxx import yyy
```

is the same as

```
import xxx
yyy = xxx.yyy  # simple assignment to a global
```

Python has no real "globals" relative to the full program. A statement like `x = 3` will always modify either a local variable, a captured variable (`nonlocal` declarations) or a module global. A "true global" simply doesn't exist (what you can do if you really need them is create a specific module for globals and refere to them with `myglobs.var` instead of `var`).

PS : The code

```
def addPoint(userInstance, comment):
    global user
    userInstance = user
    message = "current name for user: " + userInstance.getName()
```

looks very strange. The parameter `userInstance` is overwritten. May be you meant

```
user = userInstance
```

instead?

Comment: I understand this, but in your example, I am trying to change "baz" to "graz" and it is remaining as "baz". How would I fix that?

Comment: i.e. 
`user = object1` needs to be changed so that `user = object2`

Comment: I just tried using `classes.user = userData` and that did not work. I also tried `User.user = userData` which did not work to change the global `user`

Comment: updated code for accuracy. fixed `userInstance` variables to be global references. Also, I understand what you are saying but I am not importing the value of `user`. it is created at the beginning of the file as an instance of the `user class` and I am trying to change that to a different instance of that class that is read in from a .pkl file